# Do all objects inherit from NSObject?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I know you can implement using Object class but is there any in Apple's Objective C?

Comment: `NSObject` doesn't ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just about every Cocoa class inherits from `NSObject`. Even the slightly esoteric Block objects, whose class tree isn't public, have `NSObject` at the root.

The only other root class that is publicly known in Cocoa is [`NSProxy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProxy_Class/), though it does conform to the [`NSObject` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject), which allows it to act in many ways like any other Cocoa object.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it is possible to define a class that does not inherit from NSObject.

But in practice it is so difficult that no-one ever bothers to do it. NSObject does quite a lot of very nice stuff for you.